# How to write this SQL query as a LINQ statement in .NET Core (C#)?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I'm trying to join three tables together, but I just can't get my LINQ statements to get the data I want to. My SQL query that I want to replicate is like this:

```
SELECT TOP 5 SUM(Grade) AS 'TotalGrade', COUNT(Restaurants.Name) AS 'NumberOfVisits', Restaurants.Name FROM Lunches
  JOIN dbo.LunchRestaurant ON Lunches.LunchId = LunchRestaurant.LunchId
  JOIN Restaurants ON Restaurants.RestaurantId = LunchRestaurant.RestaurantId
  GROUP BY Restaurants.Name
```

The LINQ statement I currently have is:

```
    var q = from l in lunchContext.Lunches
            join lr in lunchContext.LunchRestaurant on l.LunchId equals lr.LunchId
            join r in lunchContext.Restaurants on lr.RestaurantId equals r.RestaurantId
            select new { l.Grade, r.RestaurantId};
```

But with this one, I can't get in my group by statement or the aggregate functions no matter how I try. Do you have any suggestions on what to do? There also doesn't seem to be a way to write raw SQL statements when dealing with several tables, at least not easily done in EF Core if I'm not mistaken. Otherwise that'd be an option too.

Comment: Use navigation properties, no joins.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for linq grouping.  From memory, it would be something like;

```
          var q = from l in lunchContext.Lunches
        join lr in lunchContext.LunchRestaurant on l.LunchId equals lr.LunchId
        join r in lunchContext.Restaurants on lr.RestaurantId equals r.RestaurantId
        group l by lr.RestaurantId into g
        select new { Id = g.Key,  Grade =g.Sum(x=>x.Grade)};
```

If you do need to go down the raw SQL route then you can levarage ADO.Net like this

```
using (var command = lunchContext.Database.GetDbConnection().CreateCommand())
{
    command.CommandText = "{Your sql query here}";
    context.Database.OpenConnection();
    using (var result = command.ExecuteReader())
    {
        // do something with result
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't seem to get access to the grade property/column in my anonymous object. Looks like I only have access to the middle tables keys :(

Comment: Assuming that 'Grade' is in the Lunches table, I've updated the answer to get the values from there.